# Android : How to update the Adapter immediately after fetching data from the server?

Tags: android, adapter, custom-adapter

I have 3 tabs in my MainActitvity and am fetching all the data from server. For that I have written the AsyncTask class in my MainActivity.

So the data will be applicable for all the 3 tabs. Once the data has been fetched from the server I want to update the adapter immediately. I have tried with notifyDataSetChanged(). But when I switch to other tab, data is not updating immediately. How do i solve this problem?

Please could someone help me?

Comment: Are you using 3 webservice for 3 tab or only one service

Comment: No am using single service. In that service itself am getting data for all 3 tabs.